# Where can I find Windows proxy/filter software for a network (non-desktop) machine?

Tags: proxy, monitoring, web-filtering, internet-filter

I'm looking for Windows proxy/filter software for a network (non-desktop) machine, preferably open source which is updated frequently.

So far I've only found http://www1.k9webprotection.com/, which appears to be desktop software.

I'm looking for something that would sit next to the ISP gateway but before the switch.

E.g.
ISP router → Windows PC with dual NIC → router → other machines

Answer (score 0):

Does your proxy have to be Windows?  If you can swing with Linux there's [**DansGuardian**](http://dansguardian.org/?page=whatisdg).

Comment: i have an existing windows machine that's always on, ideally would not like to add another machine !

Comment: @Kumar Got it.  The only other Open Source Windows proxies I know of are Squid and Apache but as far as I know you have to manually create ACL's to do your filtering there.  Probably not what you want to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can go about this several different ways. You could set up a Virtual Machine to use various content filtering solutions. Your computer need not be windows and need not be physically between the switch and the gateway. You change your DHCP settings to point at the VM, on the same network, and route the traffic through there.

I've used dansguardian extensively and it's what I would recommend. You can also try [Smoothwall Express](http://www.smoothwall.org/), which is an open source version of a commercial package that includes a filtering package (based on dansguardian) — confusing, I know :)
I also use pfSense, which has a package named [squidguard](http://www.squidguard.org/) available which will do filtering. I've never used the squidguard module but it exists.

An alternate way would be to set [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) as your DNS servers on router and, at the router level, block DNS requests going anywhere except OpenDNS. They have extensive DNS filtering options. Not foolproof, but easiest to set up.